# UE4 How to integrate score API to game sites?

Tags: html, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, kongregate

I am able to create a very simple 2D game using the Blueprint Project with basic scoring system. Before I upload the game to Kongregate, I want to implement a scoreboard uploaded to and hosted by Kongregate itself.

How do I upload player scores on game sites like Kongregate? Below is the link to their site with details only for Javascript implementation. How do I apply it in a BluePrint Project?

[Kongregate Score API](http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/kongregate-apis/stats)

Example of my VERY old game using Stencyl which has the scoring API implemented : [Lost Dungeon](http://www.kongregate.com/games/yawnm3/lost-dungeon)

Answer (score 0):

Kongregate does not offer a special api for ue4/blueprints.

You can however setup a webservice using their javascript api and talk to that from your game.